# Save line breaks (in database)

Tags: php, sql

Is there any possibility in PHP to save new lines in an textarea into a sql database?

I mean without typing in html commands like br ?

If not, how its done here? And how i can install it into my programm?

Thanks for help!

```
$descriptionraw = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['setdescription']);
$description = nl2br($descriptionraw);
```

Comment: newlines will be saved to your database, its up to you how to convert them when you output the data by wrapping the text in `<pre>` or using `nl2br()`

Comment: Data in, data out. The data will be saved exactly as you specify, line breaks, html tags, and all. It's when you output the data that you need to convert the line breaks (`\r\n`) to html tags, most likely with `nl2br`

Comment: @aynber okay, but how can i say php when i hit Enter he have to save the following text in a new row?

Comment: You can convert it with nl2br before you insert it, or when you display it. That's up to you.

Comment: @aynber please take a look on my updated question, i've tried this but it is'nt working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The premise of this question is flawed, as the newlines *are* stored in the database already.
At least as long as you haven't done anything to remove them prior to saving the input, that is.

The question should be how to *display* the newlines in HTML pages, and for this you have a couple of methods.

- Either use a `<pre>` tag around the output. This will cause the text to be showns **pre**formatted, and thus include the newlines as actual content. The bad side about this is that the text won't break normally, and as such can (and will) break out of the natural flow of your page.
- Or use `nl2br()` or a custom `nl2p()` function, when echoing the content to the browser. This translates the newlines into `<br>` (or `<p>`) tags, and will follow the normal flow of your site's layout. Which makes this the recommended method.

PS: This line is *wrong*:

```
 $description = nl2br($descriptionraw);
```

This is function to format `output` to a HTML-compatible viewer, a database is not. Using `nl2br()` and similar functions before you save stuff to the database will only cause you headaches, especially if you ever want to view the data in something that is not equipped to handle HTML code. (Such as the native MySQL client.)

Quick and dirty examples, using PDO:
First for saving the data:

```
$input = filter_var ($_POST['input'], FILTER);
$stmt = $db->prepare ("INSERT INTO `table`(`input`) VALUES (:data)");
$stmt->exec (array (':data' => $input));
```

Then for displaying it:

```
$output = '';
$res = $db->exec ("SELECT `input` FROM `table`");
foreach ($res->fetchArray () as $row) {
    $output .= nl2br ($row['input']);
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is perfect.

Comment: @scythe: Glad I could help, and thanks for the upvote. :)

Answer (score -1):

User php function nl2br

```
echo nl2br("This\r\nis\n\ra\nstring\r");
```

Comment: This<br />
is<br />
a<br />
string<br />

Comment: That doesnt answers my question, cause i have to put in special symbol sequences to begin a new row, right?